# Pgcrypto in different DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to use pgcrypto in postgresql-10, but I can't make it work in database different from the default one(postgres), even after a CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto ; in the specific DB. Has someone got an idea about this problem?

In the default db 'postgres' function like crypt() or gen_salt works flawlessly.

Comment: Describe the symptoms. Do you see the functions in `\dx+ pgcrypto`?

Comment: it is always a good manners to post output of commands. like `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;select crypt('a','ab');` - otherwise we have to believe you more than postgres